# How to get the available space of $HOME as a variable in shell scripting?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am writing a `bash script` to install a program for different users.

For that I want to make sure that each user has at least `500Mb` available in their  `$HOME`. My `$HOME` directory looks as follows

```
jen@ser23:~$ df -h
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                            2,9G  1,1G  1,7G  40% /
udev                                 10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                13G   826M   12G   7% /run
/dev/sda3                            15G   9,8G   4,1G   71% /usr
tmpfs                                32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                5,0M    0   5,0M  0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/local_disk_1-tmp         3,7G   21M  3,7G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/local_disk_1-opt         20G   2,0G   18G   10% /opt
/dev/mapper/local_disk_1-project1    401G  287G  114G  72% /project1
/dev/mapper/local_disk_1-var         3,8G  1,7G  1,7G  50% /var
/dev/mapper/local_disk_1-project2    99G   70G   29G   71% /project2
/dev/mapper/local_disk_1-usr_local   2,0G  3,4M  1,9G   1% /usr/local
nfs4.sf0.ise.fhg.de:/g/6/TSB/Archiv  632T  349T  276T  56% /net/p/600/groupdrives/TSB/Archiv
nfs4.sf0.ise.fhg.de:/home            632T  349T  276T  56% /net/home
tmpfs                                6,4G     0  6,4G   0% /run/user/12419
tmpfs                                6,4G  4,0K  6,4G   1% /run/user/13471
tmpfs                                6,4G  4,0K  6,4G   1% /run/user/9351
tmpfs                                6,4G     0  6,4G   0% /run/user/13142
```

My idea is to use `df -h /path/to/home | awk` but I am not sure how I can get the actual available space from `df -h`. Any help please? Thanks, Jen.

```
jen@ser23:~$ df -P /net/home/j/jen
Filesystem                1024-blocks    Used Available Capacity Mounted on
nfs4.sf0.dfd.fhg.de:/home     5242880 1026048   4216832      20% /net/home
```

Comment: Btw. I suggest to add option `-P` to your `df` command.

Comment: Not Homework is it?

Comment: @EODCraft Staff : Nop! :)

Comment: `df -P /path/to/home | awk 'NR>1 {print $4}'`?

Comment: @Cyrus: jen@ser23:~$ df -P /net/home/j/jen | awk 'NR>1 {print $4}'
4865024

Comment: It should be 1,7G

Comment: Add output of `df -P /net/home/j/jen` to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus : added :)

Comment: There's no 1,7G. There's at the moment 4216832.

Comment: Ah! I thought I should actually get the space in the partition `/dev/sda1                            2,9G  1,1G  1,7G  40% /`

Comment: If you’re on a big shared system, it’s quite possible that individual accounts have quotas, separate from the available mounted storage. For example, at my old institution, you used the `diskquota` command to check the available space. You may want to check if an equivalent system exists at your institution.

Comment: I guess the first question to ask is what program are you using to limit user space?

Answer (score 4):

The important point to remember is that `df` operates on *filesystems*, which may be attached to particular folders, and if you specify a path or file, it will resolve to usage of the filesystem on which file/folder resides. So `df -P /net/home/j/jen` operates on the filesystem mounted at `/net/home`, which is  `nfs4.sf0.ise.fhg.de` network attached storage apparently.

The usage of a *directory* and all the files requires a recursive solution that will traverse files and directories within particular directory. The tool that you seek then, is `du` and in particular `du -shx /net/home/user`.

Keypoints (for more read [man du](https://linux.die.net/man/1/du)):

- `du` is recursive by default
- `-s` provides summary instead of listing filesizes individually
- `-h` provides human readable output. If you require further processing on data, `-b` might be more preferable.
- `-x` is to keep `du` descending into another. For instance, you could have another network server attached to `/net/home/user/anotherplace`, so processing that directory is undesirable as it will give incorrect filesystem usage results.

Considering that this is an assignment, further processing and manipulations on output of `du` are left to the reader to implement

Answer (score 2):

No need to parse `df` output with `awk`, you can use `--output` switch:

```
df --output=avail "$HOME" | tail -n1
```

---

> **--output[=FIELD_LIST]**
>   use the output format defined by FIELD_LIST, or print all fields if FIELD_LIST is omitted.
>
> **FIELD_LIST** is a comma-separated list of columns to be included.  Valid field names are: 'source', 'fstype', 'itotal', 'iused', 'iavail', 'ipcent', 'size', 'used', 'avail', 'pcent', 'file' and  'tar‐
>          get'

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're heading towards a workable solution already in the comments, but I'm going to throw this in:

```
DFHOME=$( df $HOME | awk {'print $4;'} | tail -n 1 )
if [ $DFHOME -lt 500000 ]; then 
  echo "You don't got enough space!";
fi
```

I'd recommend not using -h because if the size is small enough, the G will turn to an M and your solution might break.